# removing page number for title page

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I'm using `titlepage` to create a title/abstract page for a paper, and I don't want a page number to appear, so I use the following fragment:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}
  \maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\end{titlepage}
```

inside a default article class. While the page number resets correctly (so the second page is labelled '1'), the page number '1' still appears on the first page. I'm sure there's some obvious mistake I'm making here, and would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Short answer: Don't use `\maketitle` within a `titlepage` environment, see the discussion at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27543/4012.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

`\maketitle` sets the page style to `plain`, so you need to move `\thispagestyle{empty}` to *after* `\maketitle`:

```
\clearpage\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: that made the page start at page 2 for me. How do you get it to start at page 1 after the title page and contents page?

Comment: @Magpie Did you use a `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`? That `titlepage` environment would make the page numbering start at page 1 again after the title page. But anyway, if you're _not_ using `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`, a `\setcounter{page}{1}` after your `\maketitle` should do the trick

Comment: +1 "`\maketitle` sets the page style to plain" was a lifesaver.

Comment: How to reset page number? Seems it starts from 2.

Comment: It worked for me to simply reverse these:
`\thispagestyle{empty} \clearpage\maketitle`

Answer (score 16):

Instead of using `titlepage`, you can use the environment `titlingpage` from the [titling](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titling) package. From its manual: "The pagestyle [of `titlingpage`] is `empty`; at the end it starts another ordinary page numbered page 1."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling,lipsum}
\title{This is title of my document}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{abstract}
    \end{titlingpage}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```