# What does the titlepage environment do and what are its benefits?

Tags: environments, titles, article

I'm speaking about the `article` document class only, because `report` and `book` deal with titles in a different way.

Obviously, the `titlepage` environment triggers a new page after it, and it resets the page counter to start at 1 over again. As long as you don't use `\maketitle` on your `titlepage`, the page style is set to `empty`, i.e. no page number is shown on the title page. If, however, you do use `\maketitle` within the `titlepage` environment, that sets the pagestyle to `plain` (page number in the footer) again, resulting in two consecutive pages numbered "1".

If we go a step further and use `hyperref`, which is pretty standard package, we get a warning about the page number 1 being used twice:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has 
been already used, duplicate ignored
```

This shows how `titlepage` messes up internal references slightly.

This question is not about how to fix the things `titlepage` messes up, I've got all that figured out; I'm rather wondering what the point of using `titlepage` in a non-trivial document is – besides the nice semantic markup in the source. I could as well just use `\newpage`, considering that I've got to fix the page numbering at any rate. So:

**What precisely does the `titlepage` environment do and what are its benefits?**

If you want to see the phenomena I described, here's a MWE for you to copy. The lines appended with `% *` might be interesting to comment out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}% *

\author{John Doe}
\title{Foo Bar}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle% *
Baz
\end{titlepage}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

Thanks to Werner for the answer. I haven't accepted it though because I'm still not really clear on some things. Let me clarify my question – it'd be great if Werner or someone else could elaborate a bit on them:

- What exactly does the `titlepage` environment (not the document class option) in `article` do; what macros and environments does it change and how? I looked into `article.cls` but I didn't understand all of the relevant parts.
- What is the point of using this environment after all? Why don't I just write `\newpage` after the title page?

---

**Edit 2:**

It'd be interesting to hear if you personally are actually using the `titlepage` environment and perhaps to see a small example in which it is used advantageously.

Comment: You can't combine the environment `titlepage` with `maketitle`. `maketitle` based on the idea of  `documentclass` and with `titlepage` you can define your own title. Every `documentclass` has the option `titlepage`.

Comment: A few years later, can you change the question not to have the **edits** and make the text a bit more readable?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As [@Marco](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco) mentioned in his comment, "every documentclass" provides the `titlepage` environment - you won't find it as part of [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co). However, it is probably best to view these macros and environments as they are defined in the class files: [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), [`book.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co) and [`report.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co).

However, some discussion may also be warranted.

When looking at the `titlepage` environment in these document classes, it merely provides a shell that is used by some other macros/environments. For example, setting the documentclass option `titlepage` (or `notitlepage`) modifies the way `titlepage` is defined. This option also affects the way the `abstract` environment is typeset, since it is done inside `titlepage`. Also, `\maketitle` is typeset inside `titlepage` with this option set for the documentclass.

Finally, `\maketitle` is a macro that "self-destructs" after you use it, since it's definition includes `\global\let\maketitle\relax` towards the end. So, you use it **and** you lose it. Whereas the usage of the `titlepage` environment lives well beyond `\maketitle`; hence it's use in other parts of the document as a wrapper. And, the above definitions are similar across the document classes.

In terms of the usage difference between `\maketitle` and `titlepage`: They shouldn't be mixed.

---

**Edit**:

- `article.cls` (as well as the other `book.cls` and `report.cls` document classes) initiates loading of many of its basic functionality based on a compatibility condition `\if@compatibility`. That is, certain options/macros/environments are only available if `\@compatibilitytrue`, or vice versa. If you want a toned-down version of `article.cls`, use

  ```
  \makeatletter\@compatibilitytrue\makeatother
  \documentclass{article}
  ```

The default is to load `article` with `\@compatibilityfalse`, are just leaving out the compatibility requirement all together. For a complete discussion on this topic, see [What's the use of the @compatibility condition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31838/5764). This condition also governs the declaration of the `titlepage` environment. Assuming that one loads the standard document class(es) as-is, `titlepage` is defined as follows:

```
\newenvironment{titlepage}
  {\if@twocolumn
     \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
   \else
     \@restonecolfalse\newpage
   \fi
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \setcounter{page}\@ne
  }%
  {\if@restonecol\twocolumn \else \newpage \fi
   \if@twoside\else
     \setcounter{page}\@ne
   \fi
  }
```

From this it is clear that the (traditional) `titlepage` environment does the following

- at `\begin{titlepage}`:

  - Conditions on whether the document is in `twocolumn` mode or not. If this is the case (`\@twocolumntrue`), then switch to one column mode (`\onecolumn`) and set a flag to restore to two column mode `\@restonecoltrue`. Otherwise, if already in one column mode, issue `\newpage`;
  - Clear the page headings `\thispagestyle{empty}`; and
  - Set the page counter to one `\setcounter{page}{@ne}`.
- at `\end{titlepage}`:

  - Restore two column mode if need be (set at `\begin{titlepage}`), or issue another `\newpage`; and
  - Reset the page counter to one if not in `twoside` mode `\setcounter{page}{@ne}`.

In essence, `titlepage` is meant for a single, one column page without headings. You're free to do inside of it what as you please. Perhaps that answers your second question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that's what I was looking for. After all, it seems to me that there isn't really a good reason for me to use `titlepage`. It might be a nice shortcut if you're writing a two-column document, but besides that, it's just easier to set everything correctly by hand.

Answer (score 17):

You can cure both problems, that is, the page number on the title page and the message from **hyperref** by saying

```
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\end{titlepage}
```

The page number will be set to one by `\end{titlepage}` for the following page.

The problems are:

- `\maketitle` issues a `\thispagestyle{plain}` instruction, that we can countermand with another `\thispagestyle`;
- **hyperref** doesn't like to have two pages with the same number, either it appears in print or not; setting the page number to 0 solves the issue.

This explains briefly how to cope with the major problem of using the environment with **hyperref**. Now I'll come to the reason why such an environment is provided with **article**. It was customary in many academic institutions to collect preprints with a cardboard cover page; a small window  showed the title. With the `titlepage` environment the author could place the data so that it showed properly without tampering with the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: So, as opposed to @Marco's comment above, you're saying that `titlepage` was/is supposed to be used in combination with `maketitle`?

Comment: @doncherry No. Modifying `\maketitle` for printing a title suitable for those windows requires much more work than writing a `minipage` to be shifted in the correct place.

Comment: Ah, I thought by "without tampering with the `\maketitle` command" you meant "without altering it", but you actually meant "without using it". So for that case, `titlepage` once again is (mostly) just a nice semantic wrapper?

Comment: @doncherry Yes, it takes care of temporarily reverting from a `twocolumn` setting in the class options, as Werner explained, and provides users with a blank sheet where to do whatever they want.

Comment: I see the `twocolumn` advantage, but besides that, isn't any LaTeX'ed page a "blank sheet to do whatever I want"? (I'm sorry if I'm a bit slow here, I'm just really having a hard time seeing the point of this environment.)