# Finding Information about Class Level Commands

Tags: documentclass-writing, latex-base

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands)

I'm working on writing a company-specific class file for reports in LaTeX and I thought I would start by reading `report.cls`.  I'm having a difficult time finding concise definitions of the commands/macros available in class file writing.  For example, what does `\p@` do?  What about `\@plus`?  Where is `\@compatibility` defined?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/whats-the-use-of-the-compatibility-condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\documentclass` is loaded *after* some default LaTeX commands, defined in a combined source called [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) (this is in addition to the roughly 900 TeX primitives and macros loaded/defined by default). Some of the macros defined in `latex.ltx` is done for the sake of brevity and/or consistency, like:

```
\newdimen\p@ \p@=1pt % this saves macro space and time
\newdimen\z@ \z@=0pt % can be used both for 0pt and 0
%...
\def\@minus{minus}
\def\@plus{plus}
```

In terms of the compatibility condition, consider reading [What's the use of the @compatibility condition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/whats-the-use-of-the-compatibility-condition)

For what it's worth, and as future reference, consider browsing through the "[unpacked LaTeX catalogue on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/unpacked)". `latex.ltx` is mostly built up from the sources `lt*.dtx`. When viewing `latex.ltx`, each reference used is clearly marked by the original source.