# title page in the same page with other elements

Tags: titles

I created a title page with command:

```
\title
\author
```

but when I add in the page of the title some elements another page is created and the title is   in that new page created. How can I join title and other element such as figures in only one page?

```
\begin{titlepage}

\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Immagini/unict}

\title{Scelta di un progetto di investimento}
\author{Vincenzo Pomona \\  Salvatore Mazzarino}
\maketitle

\end{titlepage}
```

**Edit**

My document class is `book`

Comment: Could you give a MWE?

Comment: I added a MWE.now should be clearer

Comment: @Mazzy: Where? Please read: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27543/4012. I'd say: Just don't use `titlepage`.

Answer (score 6):

`\maketitle` makes an additional title page; creating its own `titlepage` environment. Just remove your `\maketitle`.

The idea is *either* to a) create an automated title page with `\author`, `\title`, etc. and `\titlepage`, OR b) create a hand-made title page with `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`.

If you delete `\maketitle` and make your own title page, don't forget to fill in `\title` and `\author` in the preamble of your document (before `\begin{document}`, since the class file will probably use this information for headers and things like that.