# Abstract and title together on the first page of an article

Tags: titles, abstract

My current setup looks like this:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{The important role of ducks in CSI teams}
\author{Masi}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        For over a century, fingerprints have been an undisputed
        personal identifier.  Recent court rulings have sparked
        interest in verifying unique ...
    \end{abstract}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This will print the abstract on a separate page, but I want the abstract and the title together as shown in the picture below. How can I achieve that?

[image: masiTitleAbstract]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As explained [earlier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27543/what-does-the-titlepage-environment-do-and-what-are-its-benefits), the `titlepage` class option uses the `titlepage` environment to typeset title (`\maketitle`) and abstract (`abstract`-environment), which leads to a new page being issued. Using package `titling`, you can use the environment `titlingpage` and put `\maketitle` and the abstract in there.  This is even more handy for `twocolumn` documents.

The pagenumbering starts on the page next to the title with number 1, unless of course the document is typeset `twoside` as explained in [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192870/how-to-use-pagenumbering-in-the-document/208208#208208)

[image: masiTitleAbstractSol]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{The important role of ducks in CSI teams}
\author{Masi}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        For over a century, fingerprints have been an undisputed
        personal identifier.  Recent court rulings have sparked
        interest in verifying unique techniques to make the current
        methods even more reliable. Ducks, as they do not have
        fingers, play a key role in the development of new methods to
        protect the innocent of our society.
    \end{abstract}
\end{titlingpage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this, but shouldn't it be `\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}` instead of `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: @jim notitlepage is the default for article

Answer (score 36):

The abstract appears on its own page because you've specified the `titlepage` option to the `article` document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, titlepage]{article}
```

If you remove this option (or specify `notitlepage`), then the abstract will appear on the first page, together with the article title, author, and date:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{article}
```

Then, if you want the first section of the article to start on a new page, you should add a `\clearpage` command:

```
\clearpage
\section{First Section}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Which one should I use: \clearpage or \newpage?

One problem arised: How can I have pagenumbers start, where the section first occurs?

Comment: The difference between \clearpage and \newpage is that \clearpage ensures that any floats (e.g, figures and tables) are output before starting the new page. In this case either \clearpage or \newpage would work. I tend to use \clearpage out of habit.

Comment: Does someone have a solution for the problem Masi mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the page start where the first section occurs you should put `\thispagestyle{empty}` on each page you don't want numbered and `\setcounter{page}{1}` on the page you want it to start numbering on.