# Title and abstract together on the first page of a report

Tags: page-breaking, titles, abstract, report

I've just read this:

[Abstract and title together on the first page of an article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69551/abstract-and-title-together-on-one-page)

Can I achieve the same for a report? If I use the same code in a report-class document, I still get a page break between the title and the abstract.

Example document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{This is my title}
\author{Me myself and I}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{titlingpage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might consider not using `\maketitle`  at all.

Answer (score 3):

A hackish way to do it, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3408428/1593077), is placing the `\maketitle` within a `minipage`, so its page-clearing is "contained" and doesn't really affect the outer document:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{This is my title}
\author{Me myself and I}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}
\end{minipage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this will prevent footnotes from being set on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\maketitlehookd` hook for this. Note that the abstract is input *before* `\maketitle`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox{\abstractbox}
\renewenvironment{abstract}
 {%
  \global\setbox\abstractbox=\vtop\bgroup
  \begin{center}\bfseries\abstractname\end{center}%
 }
 {\par\egroup}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{%
  \par\vfil
  \box\abstractbox
}

\title{This is my title}
\author{Me myself and I}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\begin{abstract}
\blindtext\blindtext
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do we need both the titling package and the custom command?

Comment: Also, with this in place, I get an error message when placing a footnote inside `\author`.

Comment: @einpoklum And where should the footnote appear?

Comment: On the bottom of the title page; I can't think of another option. Note that my super-hacky solution has a similar problem.

Comment: @einpoklum `\author{Me\thanks{Thanks}}` does the job cleanly.