# Document has 2 first pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

the watermark appears on 2 pages, the title and the first TOC. After some testing I think the TOC resets the page numbering. If I insert a blank page after the title, the page of the start of the TOC is still one.

```
\documentclass[12pt,runningheads]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,hyperref,array,xcolor,multicol,verbatim,mathpazo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{24pt}
\newwatermark[firstpage,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{Vorabgabe}
\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\title{XXXXX\\ XXX }

\author{XXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\section{XXXX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The description and the code is not really helpful since incomplete. Please add `\documentclass` etc., the *relevant* packages and `\end{document}` to your post

Comment: Thanks! these are the relevant pages (?) the first page is twice, so the watermark appears on the title page and the first TOC page

Comment: Leander: **packages**, not **pages** ;-) Your example above will not compile! And `\begin{tableofcontents}\tableofcontents\end{tableofcontents}` really looks weird

Comment: ah sry :D thanks! i am new to tex....as you would have guessed :)

Comment: Leander: I supposed so

Comment: You should not combine `titlepage` and `maketitle`, cf. for instance [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27543/34551).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use the `\maketitle` command, *or* uses the `titlepage` environment, but not both at the same times.

### With `\maketitle`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[firstpage,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{Vorabgabe}

\title{XXXXX\\ XXX }
\author{XXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\tableofcontents

\section{XXXX}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `titlepages`

You could have some fancier display of the title but for some reason, *indeed* the `xwatermark` package display twice the watermark when the `firstpage` option is given.
This is not the expected behaviour, and I don't know how to patch it.

Comment: You linked to a post by Werner in the comments to the question. Werner also explains that the titlepage indeed resets the page number for the standard classes. If you peek into `classes.dtx` you will see, who is to blame ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best solution, but if you want the watermark to appear only at the titlepage, you may set that page to any desired number, and then choose the watermark to appear only at that one instead of 'firstpage':

```
\newwatermark[page=100,...]{Vorabgabe}

\begin{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{100}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
```