# How to suppress page number on cover page?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [removing page number for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/removing-page-number-for-title-page)

I'm using the following code to create my front cover:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{400mm}(0mm,0mm)
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{front.jpg}
\end{textblock*}
\end{document}
```

But I'm getting a page number '1' at the bottom of the front cover image. How can I suppress that?

Comment: duplicate http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1736/9467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\thispagestyle{empty}` just before your `textblock`. This removes both header and footer (containing your page number).