# Include a page in numbering but not display its number

Tags: titles, page-numbering, roman-numerals

I have started the beginning of a report with roman page numbering for the title and contents pages. My instructor has said he wants the title page to be numbered page (i) but he does not want it to show the page number. How can this be done?

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the instruction

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

immediately *after* `\maketitle`.

Remark: it's essential to execute `\thispagestyle{empty}` *after* `\maketitle`. See, e.g., the posting [removing page number for title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1736/5001) for what happens if you reverse the ordering of the two instructions.

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % <- new
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}  
...
```