# Include title page in numbering via preamble settings only?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, preamble, sphinx

I'm trying to make my title page count as "Page 1" in my PDF, but I have the restriction that (I think) I can only make a change to the preamble section of my .tex file.

My scenario is that I'm using sphinx-doc (with Read the Docs) to generate a PDF of our project's documentation, so I (think?) I can only make changes in the sphinx conf.py file which go into the LaTeX preable. (In other words, I don't have access to the generated .tex file before it's processed into a PDF.)

In our case, our users are reading this PDF on their devices, so I want the page numbers in the PDF to "match" the actual page count numbers of the document and the TOC.

I have figured out how to switch the numbering to arabic, but the problem is everything is off by 1. A page linked in the TOC as "Page 13" is actually Page 14 of the PDF.

I assume this is because the title page isn't being counted as a number?

I looked at other answers ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171976/forcing-page-number-to-start-from-the-title-page) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297961/include-a-page-in-numbering-but-not-display-its-number)), but it seems that those require inline changes to the .tex file which I'm not able to do?

So I wonder if I can do this from the preamble?

Here's what I'm adding into my preamble via the sphinx config so far:

```
    \renewcommand\thesection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \usepackage{bera}
    \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
    \usepackage{inconsolata}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \AtBeginDocument{\raggedright}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 2):

A rather radical way is to inject `\renewcommand\pagenumbering[1]{}` in the preamble of the generated LaTeX file. You do this via the `'preamble'` key (check the [docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-latex_elements)).

It worked for me in my testing (for document of the `'manual'` type, i.e. using `report` class).