# Add page break after tableofcontent via preamble?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, preamble, sphinx

Is it possible to add a page break after the table of contents in the preamble rather than inline in the .tex file?

This question is somewhat related to the other one I asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341897/include-title-page-in-numbering-via-preamble-settings-only), though since it's a different question I thought I should do another post.

Basically I'm using Sphinx with Read the Docs, so I don't have access to the generated .tex file before it's processed into a PDF, meaning I have to make any changes I do to the preamble section.

My current doc class is "report", but the content starts on the same page as the last partial page of the table of contents, whereas I'd like to start it on the next page if that's possible?

Here's what I'm adding to the preamble so far from my Sphinx config file:

```
    \renewcommand\thesection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \usepackage{bera}
    \usepackage[defaultsans]{lato}
    \usepackage{inconsolata}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \AtBeginDocument{\raggedright}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: `\renewcommand\thesection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}` eeek! really?

Comment: `\let\oldtablefocontents\tableofcontents \renewcommand\tableofcontents{\oldtableofcontents\clearpage}`

Comment: For the `\renewcommand\thesection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}`, I added that because when I got rid of the section numbers, the section headings were still indented. I don't really know what I'm doing so I googled and found that, but I guess I can google more for a proper left justification.

For the `\let\oldtablefocontents\tableofcontents \renewcommand\tableofcontents{\oldtableofcontents\clearpage}`, I'm not sure if that's a suggested answer? When I add those lines, the TOC disappears altogether.

Comment: it shouldn't make the toc go, it just adds `\clearpage` to the end of the definition. presumably your method of removing section numbers was incorrect should just be `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed my two lines
`\renewcommand\thesection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}
    \renewcommand\thesubsection{\hspace*{-0.5em}}`
and replaced them with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` and that works to remove the numbering and they're positioned correctly. But all other forms of `\let\oldtablefocontents\tableofcontents \renewcommand\tableofcontents{\oldtableofcontents\clearpage}` still give errors. I tried two lines, one line, second line starting with `\renewcommand` etc., but they all result in the TOC being gone. Thanks for the numbering tip!

Comment: as an update, I changed my Sphinx config to just use the TOC from my master_doc instead of the text content, and that seems to have fixed the issue, so I guess I'm good now?

Comment: Sphinx is the [Sphinx Documentation Generator](http://www.sphinx-doc.org). One of its options is to generate PDFs using tex.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is fixed.

My first thought was to just add a blank section in the top of my TOC. That worked, but I felt like it was a hack.

Then I realized that Sphinx has an [option for latex](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/config.html#confval-latex_documents) where you can set `toctree_only=True` which means that it will ignore text content from your master doc and only use the TOC from it, and when I set that, it fixes the problem. The first doc starts on the next page. So I'm going to call this 'answered' now.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: perhaps you could use something like ``.. only:: not latex`` in the master doc file.